# Crystal Reports for VS2010

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports

I'm having some issues getting crystal reports working nicely with our applications. And i cannot seem to find any resources that answer my question.

Basically, we have a crystal report, designed in the crystal reports application with it's own datasource.

Now when i add this to VS and display it, i need to setup a connection on the PC using MYSQL ODBC Datasource configuration tool, however even with this datasource setup, the crystalreports viewer askes for a password, and even suppling the correct password will show a "login failed. please try again" error message.

Ideally what i would like to know, is

A) is it possible and if so how, can i setup the connection in VS2010 so that i wont need to go around using MYSQL ODBC Datasource configuration tool on every PC i deploy my application too.

B) why does this connection always fail, the credentials are correct (we've tested multiple times, and the report & connection function perfectly from within crystal reports)

Hopefully you guys can help me out, my google fu has failed me.

Answer (score 1):

If the Crystal Report allows for the username and password to the mySQL stored procedure to be passed to the report through the ReportViewer object, you have to use .NET code-behind to set the credentials via the:

```
ReportViewer.ServerReport.ReportServerCredentials
```

property of the ReportViewer instance.

Here's an example:

```
System.Net.NetworkCredential networkCredentials = 
          new System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "password", "domain");

reportViewer.ServerReport.ReportServerCredentials = networkCredentials;
```

Comment: We're using the crystalreports view from SAP - SAPBusinessObjects.WPF.Viewer which does not have this property. Also afaik the connection and credentials are set via the datasource, defined using the MYSQL ODBC Datasource configuration tool

Comment: Ok, figured out how to do what you suggested, the ReportDocument has a SetDatabaseLogon which once set avoided the login issue, i'm still having to create a datasource with the tool however, is there a way to avoid that?